# Does our fate get changed in the night of shab-e-barat?

Tags: qadar

In my masjid, they used to recite Surah Yasin three times on the shab-e-barat night, under the belief that it would change their fate.

Is this true?  If so, please provide relevant ahadith supporting this practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not true.  Furthermore the recitation of Surat Yaseen, and many other things, on this night are all Bid'at/Innovation in religion.  There are no Ahadeeth supporting such worships being done on this night, the ahadeeth that do exist they are either Weak (Da'eef) or Fabricated (Mawdoo').  And may Allah forgive my mistakes.

Source: [IslamQA(Arabic)](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/154850)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!